# Move only one item in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Okay i know i can move my blocks using `grid-template-areas` or `order`.
But my question is: can i move only one item to another place without changing `order` of every other block? Because that is a few lines more of code and i wonder if it can be made easier?
I have a grid:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

I want the item on the **1-st column** and **1-st row** to change position to **2-nd column** and  **1-st row**. To switch places with the other block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify the position using `grid-column` (and `grid-row` if needed) and make sure to use `grid-auto-flow:dense` to avoid empty areas:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.box * {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="grid-column:2">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes is see. My bad i only used grid-ares on one of the items which didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can still use order. Just set all the children to `order:1` and then set the `order` of the chosen item to `0`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1em;
}

.grid * {
  order:1;
}

.grid :nth-child(2) {
  order:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```